# Trouble with Die Roll Program

Tags: c, loops, dice

I wrote this program that rolls a pair of dice 20000 times. The rules are:

- If a 7 or 11 is rolled, then the player wins
- If a 2, 3, or 12 is rolled then the player loses.
- If neither of the above is rolled, then the sum is stored and the die are rolled again

Second roll rules:

- If a 7 is rolled, then the player wins
- If the same sum as before is rolled, then the player loses
- If not, the player rolls again until either of those two conditions are met.

At the end it calculates a percentage of games won.
My problem is that I should be getting a percentage of games won around 39%-60% according to a colleagues, but every time I run the program, I get around 20% and I don't understand why. Am I doing something wrong? Can someone help me please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{   
int dieOne, dieTwo, keyValue, value, wins = 0, firstWins = 0, subWins = 0, loss = 0, count=0;
double percentWin, percentFirstWins, percentSubWins;
srand(time(NULL));

do{
dieOne = rand() % 6 + 1;
dieTwo = rand() % 6 + 1;
value = dieOne + dieTwo;
count++;


if (value==7||value==11) {
    firstWins++;
    wins++;
}

else if (value== 2||value==3||value==12) {
    loss++;
}

else {
    do{ 
    keyValue = value;

    dieOne = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dieTwo = rand() % 6 + 1;
    value = dieOne + dieTwo;
    count++;

    if (value==7) {
    subWins++;
    wins++;
    }

    else if (value = keyValue) { 
        loss++;
    }

    } while ( value != 7 && value != keyValue );
}
} while (count <= 20000);

    percentWin = (double) wins/count * 100;
    percentFirstWins = (double) firstWins/count * 100;
    percentSubWins = (double) subWins/count * 100;
    printf("You won %.1lf percent of your games! \nYou won %.1lf percent of games on the first roll.\nYou won %.1lf percent of games on the second roll.\n", percentWin, percentFirstWins, percentSubWins );

    system("pause");
}
```

There are 6 possible ways to roll a 7 and two possible ways to roll an 11.
That's a total of 8 possible ways to win on the first roll.
There are 36 (6^2) possible ways to roll the dice.  This means you have an 8 in 36 chance to win on the first roll or around 22% of the time.

Moreover, we have 2 possible ways to roll a 2, and 2 possible ways to roll a 3, and 2 possible ways to roll a 12. So that means there is a 1 in 6 chance (6/36) of losing on the first roll, or about 17% of the time.

So the remaining 61% of wins and losses have to come from the second roll. Whatever the case, my program is generating a very high losing streak, whereas the programs of my colleagues seem to generate a 40-60 percent of total wins. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There's only one way to roll a 2. Same goes for 12.

Comment: Oops. Okay, so the probability of losing is about 11%. With a little more research, I found the percentage should be closer to 49%. Either way, that doesn't explain why my program isn't giving me that percentage. Ohhh I hope someone can help me...

Comment: Logic errors in the code aside, note that 'rand() % 6' is not going to be perfectly uniform, although that's probably not a big enough factor to explain the discrepancy you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what's causing your problem:

```
else if (value = keyValue) {
```

You're assigning, rather than comparing. This will always evaluate to true, thus artificially inflating your losses. You should be using `==` here instead of `=`.

Also, for rolls that are neither a win nor a loss, you're not incrementing either the `wins` or the `loss` counter for either of those, but you are adding to `count`. So you're going to end up with a situation where `wins + loss != count`. When you calculate the win percentage, try calculating it as `wins / (loss + wins)`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that now, but it's still giving me the same result.

Comment: You also have a bug in the way you're keeping track of the counts of wins and losses. See my addition to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what the problem was! I just got rid of the count++ statements and just converted the whole thing to a for loop to count the number of times it ran instead. Thanks sooo very much!